# beforeunload, как отменить реакцию на нажатие кнопки submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla

Подскажите как решить данный вопрос или сделать аналог.
На странице заносятся данные и происходит резервирование алиасов с записью их в БД. Требуется, если человек не сохранил, а просто решил выйти, закрыть, обновить или перейти на другую страницу, то должен выполниться скрипт (`ajax`), который очищает все в БД и других местах (т.е. как бы отменяет действия пользователя). Очистка происходит после выхода окна с подтверждением ухода или обновления страницы. При нажатии на сохранить - все должно без лишних вопросов сохраняться.
Я использовал следующий код:

```js
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
    var confirmationMessage = "1";

    (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage; //Gecko + IE
    return confirmationMessage;                            //Webkit, Safari, Chrome
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Все отрабатывает, как надо, за одним ОЧЕНЬ серьезным исключением!
При нажатии на кнопку "Сохранить", так же срабатывает данный код и в итоге все удаляется.
Код кнопки (вдруг это важно):

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" id="jsubmitbtn" class="btn btn-primary itemsave" onclick="Joomla.submitbutton('article.save')">
    <span class="icon-ok"></span>Сохранить    </button>
</div>
```

Видимо из за того, что после сохранения происходит редирект (а с ним ничего не поделать, он нужен), то и `beforeunload` срабатывает. Может возможно, как-то отфильтровать данный момент?

## **Дополнение**

насколько я понял изначально, `.unload()` вызывается только при положительном "ответе" в диалоговом окне `beforeunload`.  в этом видимо моя большая ошибка. Подскажите как правильно подключить его в мою конструкцию?

```js
var userClickedSave = false;
jsubmitbtn.addEventListener('click', (e)=>
{
  e.preventDefault();
  userClickedSave = true;
  Joomla.submitbutton('article.save');
}); 

window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
  if (userClickedSave)
      return;

    var confirmationMessage = "1";

    (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage; //Gecko + IE
    return confirmationMessage;                            //Webkit, Safari, Chrome
});
// удаляем строку из таблицы резервирования алиаса при обновлении или покидании страницы
$(window).unload(function () {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '../еее/file.php',
    async : false,
    data: {
      'aaa': aaa,
      'bbb': bbb
    },
    success: function(response) {
//            console.log(response);
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log('ошибка!');
    }
  });
});
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="jsubmitbtn" class="btn btn-primary itemsave" onclick="userClickedSave = true;Joomla.submitbutton('article.save')">
  <span class="icon-ok"></span><?php echo JText::_('JSAVE') ?>
</button>
```

## **Решение (в моем случае)**

и оба очень помогли, большое вам спасибо! Отмечу как "ответ" (только не знаю можно ли оба, наверное нет). не полностью решался вопрос вашими ответами, но видимо я не верно задал его.

```js
var userClickedSave = false;
jsubmitbtn.addEventListener('click', (e)=>
{
  e.preventDefault();
  userClickedSave = true;
  Joomla.submitbutton('article.save');
});

function pageCleanup()
{
  if (!userClickedSave)
    {
    // удаляем строку из таблицы резервирования алиаса при обновлении или покидании страницы
    unloadDelAjax(); // фнкция с ajax запросом
  }
}

$(window).on('beforeunload', function (e)
{
  if (userClickedSave)
    return;
  var confirmationMessage = "1";

  (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage; //Gecko + IE
  return confirmationMessage;           
  //this will work only for Chrome
  pageCleanup();
});

$(window).on("unload", function ()
{
  //this will work for other browsers
  pageCleanup();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
  var userClickedSave = false;
</script>

<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" id="jsubmitbtn" class="btn btn-primary itemsave" onclick="userClickedSave = true;Joomla.submitbutton('article.save')">
    <span class="icon-ok"></span>Сохранить              </button>
</div>


window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
  if (userClickedSave)
    return;

  var confirmationMessage = "1";

  (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage; //Gecko + IE
  return confirmationMessage;                            //Webkit, Safari, Chrome
});
```

Comment: по логике, написанное выглядит верным, но по факту все же выходит диалог от `beforeunload` и следовательно при подтверждении срабатывает и `$(window).unload(function () { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

```
jsubmitbtn.addEventListener('click', (e)=>
{
    e.preventDefault();
    userClickedSave = true;
    Joomla.submitbutton('article.save');
});
```

Вызов preventDefault предотвратит стандартное поведение браузера (редирект)

Comment: eсли правильно понял, то так же следует добавить   
  `window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
  if (userClickedSave)
    return;`  в этом случае диалогового окна нет, но  `$(window).unload(function () { ... }` так же срабатывает